# Let p be an odd prime number. Then show the following:

Tags: graph-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be prime, $p \geq 3$. Then show that $K_p$ is the union of $\frac{1}{2}(p-1)C_p$.

I am once again at a loss for a starting point. Maybe just a small hint so I can work through this myself and then return here If I still cannot figure this out. Thanks!

Comment: What is $K_p$?  What is $C_p$?

Comment: $K_p$ is the complete graph with $p$ vertices? And $C_p$ is the cycle with $p$ vertices?

Comment: Sorry - I am new to graph theory and assumed the notation was standard.  lhf is correct.

Comment: @mathtastic It is relatively standard in graph theory, but you didn't say anything about $K_p$ being a graph.  The subject tag even says number-theory :).

Comment: Oh man! I clicked the wrong tag. My fault!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find a way to decompose $K_p$ into $\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$ cycles of length p. If the vertices of $K_p$ are $v_1, v_2, ..., v_p$, then the first cycle could have edges of the form $v_iv_{i+1}$ (where the subscripts are read mod p), the second cycle could have edges of $v_iv_{i+2}$, and so on... the $\frac{1}{2}(p-1)$th cycle could have edges of $v_iv_{i+\frac{1}{2}(p-1)}$.

Now prove that all the edges are covered by one of these cycles: Each edge is in the form $v_iv_j$ for some i,j, and $\min(i-j \mod p, j-i \mod p)$ should be $\le \frac{p}{2}$. In fact, that should be $\le \frac{p-1}{2}$ since we want it to be an integer. So it is covered by the $\min(i-j \mod p, j-i \mod p)$-th cycle above.